# copy dependencies using some wildcard on groupid using maven dependency plugin copy mojo

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to copy dependencies from a war packaged project after applying some filtering on the groupid using some sort of pattern matching so that groupids matching a pattern are copies. Is it possible ?

This will help in not listing the artifacts individually.

Comment: What is the purpose of that?

Comment: To avoid individual listing of artifacts for inclusion/exclusion